# Suggestions for a custom web part in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint

I have a list created for the purpose of displaying news. So, the columns are: Title, Content and Created. For example, I'd like the list to let people know when there is a server outage planned.

What I want for the functionality of the web part is to display the title only and only the month/day the news item created in the list. I'd like a picture of a small arrow in the front of the items also (left side).

Example:

"
News Web Part
=> Server outage planned for this Saturday (06/23)
=> Server updates today (06/22)

"

I would like the user to be able to click on the titles of these items and it will go to a page that gives more information (Content column, rich text), instead of pop that AJAX window like what happens by default when you click on a list item.

Does this require Visual Studio? If not, is something like this possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend making a list to store the information that you want to provide to the end user via the SharePoint UI. Once you have your list create a view, Order it by most recently created and limit the number of items displayed to as many as you wish to display to the user.

Add a list web part(XSLTListViewWebPart) and point that at a view you have created.

This will give you something pretty basic visually.

You will then need to look in to XSLT to apply a style to that web part. There are loads of articles on google of how to do this.

You do not need to do this in visual studio, I sometimes just use notepad ++ for small things like this. The above should be enough for you to get started.

Cheers

Truez